# WebSphere 5.1 to 6.1 Migration Error

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, axis

I am working on a Java 1.4 web application that uses Axis 1 web services.  The application calls a web service developed and hosted by a third party partner.  Our production environment is running WebSphere 5.1 and the application is running just fine.  We need to migrate our servers off of 5.1  to 6.1 for security reasons.  We began by upgrading our development environment to 6.1.  In our development environment we decided to update the app to Java 1.5 in addition to the WebSphere migration.  The application on dev is working just fine.  All the web service calls execute correctly, with the exception of one.  This particular call always returns with the following error.

**No mapping found for 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:string' using encoding style 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'**

Does anyone have any ideas why all the WS would work except this one?  I have not changed the code base, just what version compiler I am using.  Since it works on prod I am not sure what I could have done to mess up dev.

My Google-Fu has failed me at the point.  Any info you can provide is most appreciated!

WSDL

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<!--Generated by the Oracle JDeveloper 10g Web Services WSDL Generator-->
<!--Date Created: Thu Jul 08 13:27:58 PDT 2004-->
<definitions
   name="CSIWebService"
   targetNamespace="http://mil/dcma/csi/ws/CSIWebService.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://mil/dcma/csi/ws/CSIWebService.wsdl"
   xmlns:ns1="http://mil.dcma.csi.ws/ICSIWebService.xsd">
   <types>
      <schema
         targetNamespace="http://mil.dcma.csi.ws/ICSIWebService.xsd"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSCSIServiceResponse" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="results" type="ns1:ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSContract"/>
               <element name="comments" type="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSStatusCommentary"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSContract" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="cage" type="string"/>
               <element name="dodaac" type="string"/>
               <element name="latestModDate" type="string"/>
               <element name="lineItemIds" type="ns1:ArrayOfString"/>
               <element name="lineItems" type="ns1:ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSLineItem"/>
               <element name="piinDodaac" type="string"/>
               <element name="piinSerial" type="string"/>
               <element name="piinType" type="string"/>
               <element name="piinYear" type="string"/>
               <element name="spiin" type="string"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="ArrayOfString" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <complexContent>
               <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                  <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
               </restriction>
            </complexContent>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSLineItem" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="fobSite" type="string"/>
               <element name="inspectAcceptCode" type="string"/>
               <element name="itemName" type="string"/>
               <element name="lineItemId" type="string"/>
               <element name="nsn" type="string"/>
               <element name="partNumber" type="string"/>
               <element name="piin" type="string"/>
               <element name="quantityAccepted" type="int"/>
               <element name="quantityShipped" type="int"/>
               <element name="serviceCompletionDate" type="string"/>
               <element name="serviceCompletionEstimatedFlag" type="string"/>
               <element name="spiin" type="string"/>
               <element name="spnRecipient" type="string"/>
               <element name="totalUnits" type="int"/>
               <element name="totalUnitsEstimatedFlag" type="string"/>
               <element name="unitCost" type="double"/>
               <element name="unitCostEstimatedFlag" type="string"/>
               <element name="unitOfMeasure" type="string"/>
               <element name="varianceOver" type="double"/>
               <element name="varianceUnder" type="double"/>
               <element name="schedules" type="ns1:ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSSchedule"/>
               <element name="shipments" type="ns1:ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSShipment"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSSchedule" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="clin" type="string"/>
               <element name="deliveryDate" type="string"/>
               <element name="deliveryDateEstimatedFlag" type="string"/>
               <element name="elin" type="string"/>
               <element name="lineItemId" type="string"/>
               <element name="markFor" type="string"/>
               <element name="milStrip" type="string"/>
               <element name="modNumber" type="string"/>
               <element name="piin" type="string"/>
               <element name="schedQuantityEstimatedFlag" type="string"/>
               <element name="scheduledQuantity" type="int"/>
               <element name="shipTo" type="string"/>
               <element name="spiin" type="string"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSSchedule" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <complexContent>
               <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                  <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSSchedule[]"/>
               </restriction>
            </complexContent>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSShipment" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="acceptanceSite" type="string"/>
               <element name="dateAccepted" type="string"/>
               <element name="dateShipped" type="string"/>
               <element name="fobSite" type="string"/>
               <element name="lineItemId" type="string"/>
               <element name="markFor" type="string"/>
               <element name="milStrip" type="string"/>
               <element name="piin" type="string"/>
               <element name="pqaSite" type="string"/>
               <element name="quantityAccepted" type="int"/>
               <element name="quantityShipped" type="int"/>
               <element name="shipmentNumber" type="string"/>
               <element name="spiin" type="string"/>
               <element name="unitOfMeasure" type="string"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSShipment" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <complexContent>
               <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                  <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSShipment[]"/>
               </restriction>
            </complexContent>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSLineItem" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <complexContent>
               <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                  <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSLineItem[]"/>
               </restriction>
            </complexContent>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSContract" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <complexContent>
               <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                  <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSContract[]"/>
               </restriction>
            </complexContent>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSStatusCommentary" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="comments" type="ns1:ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSStatusList"/>
               <element name="statusTypes" type="ns1:ArrayOfString"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSStatusList" jdev:packageName="mil.dcma.csi.ws" xmlns:jdev="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/webservices">
            <all>
               <element name="contents" type="ns1:ArrayOfString"/>
            </all>
         </complexType>
         <complexType name="ArrayOfmil_dcma_csi_ws_WSStatusList" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            <complexContent>
               <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                  <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSStatusList[]"/>
               </restriction>
            </complexContent>
         </complexType>
      </schema>
   </types>
   <message name="getContracts0Request">
      <part name="cage" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinDodaac" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinYear" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinType" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinSerial" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="spiin" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <message name="getContracts0Response">
      <part name="return" type="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSCSIServiceResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="getContractLineItems1Request">
      <part name="piinDodaac" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinYear" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinType" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="piinSerial" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="spiin" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="lineItemIds" type="ns1:ArrayOfString"/>
   </message>
   <message name="getContractLineItems1Response">
      <part name="return" type="ns1:mil_dcma_csi_ws_WSCSIServiceResponse"/>
   </message>
   <portType name="CSIWebServicePortType">
      <operation name="getContracts">
         <input name="getContracts0Request" message="tns:getContracts0Request"/>
         <output name="getContracts0Response" message="tns:getContracts0Response"/>
      </operation>
      <operation name="getContractLineItems">
         <input name="getContractLineItems1Request" message="tns:getContractLineItems1Request"/>
         <output name="getContractLineItems1Response" message="tns:getContractLineItems1Response"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name="CSIWebServiceBinding" type="tns:CSIWebServicePortType">
      <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name="getContracts">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"/>
         <input name="getContracts0Request">
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="CSIWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </input>
         <output name="getContracts0Response">
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="CSIWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="getContractLineItems">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"/>
         <input name="getContractLineItems1Request">
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="CSIWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </input>
         <output name="getContractLineItems1Response">
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="CSIWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="CSIWebService">
      <documentation>
This class defines Web Service messages as local
methods. Each method is a valid Web Service messages, using
RPC-style. This design is appropriate for typical Web Service
implementation toolkits such as Axis.
</documentation>
      <port name="CSIWebServicePort" binding="tns:CSIWebServiceBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://hxacacarqw025:8888/CSI/CSIWebService"/>
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information than that to get any kind of response. What's the WSDL look like, and what is the input message? And it's been years since I've used SOAP encoding. You know that style has been more-or-less deprecated for quite some time, right?

Comment: Yeah, I am aware that axis 1 is deprecated.  The application is legacy and is only supposed to be in maintenance mode.  The code hasn't been looked at in 5 years.  This was just dumped on me since the upgrade "HAS TO HAPPEN".  The past developers on this app left the company years ago.  Will update my post with the WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue ended up being that the version of our SOAP client (Axis 1) was slightly different between WebSphere 5.1 and 6.1.  Running the Axis utility function "WSDL to JAVA" updated the classes within our application.  We had to alter our code to point to these regenerated classes and rebuild.  The errors went away.  All of our web service calls perform correctly now.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

WAS 6.1 has copies of axis1 jars as well, so can you try using "parent last" flag as mentioned here:
[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fcrun_classload.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/crun_classload.html)

Comment: I will check our server settings and let you know if this has any impact.  Thank you.

Comment: The server has the parent last flag set and the issue is still present.  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html 

com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine
true

Comment: We also set a custom [JVM proptery](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html)

`com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine
true  `